# Symfony 5 book RABBITMQ_DSN

Tags: symfony5

Hello everyone and a happy new year 2021.
I am going through the symfony 5 Book and am having quite a few problems and sincerely want your help.
In fact, section 18.5, we define an environment variable "RABBITMQ_DSN" without specifying its dsn in the .env file. This code fails when I run it.
Could someone help me understand what is going on. thank you

```
+++ b/config/packages/messenger.yaml
@@ -5,10 +5,10 @@ framework:
transports:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transportconfiguration
- # async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
+ async: '%env(RABBITMQ_DSN)%'
# failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
# sync: 'sync://'
routing:
# Route your messages to the transports
- # 'App\Message\YourMessage': async
+ App\Message\CommentMessage: async
```

Comment: Well, have you tried to specify to RABBIMQ_DSN environment variable somewhere?

Comment: Yes! In the .env file

Comment: ```RABBITMQ_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/messages```

Comment: Here is the error message I am getting... ```Could not connect to the AMQP server. Please verify the provided DSN. ({"host":"localhost","port":5672,"vhost":"/","login":"guest","password":"********"}).```